# Como puedo corregir este metodo switch para que su valor sea leido por los otros metodos (Frame)

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta primera podran observar los datos, en este caso es para un boton de frame que sera para calcular esos metodos, lo del rojo de la primera es un metodo que pronto lo usare. Todo normal ahi. ¿Es valido que use `TipSeguro` para el siguiente metodo de switch?, ya que representa un combobox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la segunda imagen ahi esta presente mi problema en donde:

```Java
//Calculando el monto de Seguro
switch (TipSeguro){
    case 0:
        MontoSeguro = SueldoB * 0.17;
        break;
    case 1:
        MontoSeguro = SueldoB * 0.05;
        break;
}
```

Que debo hacer para que su resultado pase al siguiente metodo:

```Java
//Calculando el monto de descuentos
MontoDescuento = MontoSeguro + MontoEssalud;
```

Porque ahí sale el error de que la variable `MontoSeguro` no tiene valor.

Aqui esta mi código:

```Java
private void CalcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    //Declaracion de las variables.
    int TipSeguro, Area;
    String Nombre, Codigo;
    double SueldoB,
           HE, 
           PagoXHora,
           MontoXHorasE, 
           MontoSeguro,
           MontoEssalud;

    double MontoDescuento,
           SueldoBruto,
           SueldoNeto;

    //Datos de entrada
    TipSeguro = jbcxSeguro.getSelectedIndex();

    Area = jbcxArea.getSelectedIndex();

    HE = Double.parseDouble(jtxtHoras.getText());

    SueldoB = Double.parseDouble(jtxtSueldo.getText());

    //Proceso de calculos de salida

    //Llamada a funcion para el calculo del sueldo segun el seguro y area

    PagoXHora = Calculo_PagoXHoraExtra(TipSeguro,Area);

    //Metodos adicionales:

    //Calculando el monto extra
    MontoXHorasE = SueldoB * HE /240;
                    
    //Calculo del monto de Essalud
    MontoEssalud = SueldoB * 0.03;

    //Calculo del monto del sueldo Bruto
    SueldoBruto = SueldoB + MontoXHorasE;
  
    //Calculando el monto de seguro

    switch (TipSeguro){
        case 0:
            MontoSeguro = SueldoB * 0.17;
            break;
        case 1:
            MontoSeguro = SueldoB * 0.05;
            break;
    }
    
    //Calculando el monto de Descuentos 
    MontoDescuento = MontoSeguro + MontoEssalud;

    //Calculo del sueldo Neto
    SueldoNeto = SueldoBruto - MontoDescuento;

}
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que contienen codigo dentro de una imagen, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa como hacer un pregunta y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: de paso.. netbeans no es un lenguaje.. es una ide.. tu problema es con una ide, o con un lenguaje?? usa el boton [edit] y arregla tu pregunta...